# java string array specific word print out

Tags: java

New to java and trying to figure out how to print out a specific word in a string array. E.g.

```
String[] myArray = {"bread", "milk", "sugar", "coffee"}
```

I want to just print out the second value of the array (we say `milk`, I know the array index starts at `0` but just for this example we will go with this). Any ideas how to do this. I tried the for loop but cant seem to get it going so if you guys have an example it would be appreciated.

I cant exactly just print out by using index number. I will give a more detailed approach on how i would like it to work... Say I have two arrays 
String[] Array1 = {"bread", "milk", "sugar", "coffee"} 
String[] Array2 = {"butter", "tea", "spoon", "cup"} 
So if I prompted any entry from array 1 e.g. bread (I would like it to print out something like butter then) so for each value in array1 i would like it to return the value at the same index in array2.

Comment: Ok, show the for loop that you tried? May be we can help you solve it using your way only.

Comment: please specify any specific problem that you are facing

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] myArray = {"bread", "milk", "sugar", "coffee"}
for(int i=0;i<myArray.length;i++){
    if(myArray[i].equals("milk")){
       System.out.println(myArray[i]); //Matching the string and printing.
    }
}
System.out.println(myArray[1]); //printing the 2nd element if you don't care about the value
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
System.out.println(myArray[1]);
```

### [Demo at www.ideone.com](http://ideone.com/4qtrT9)

---

If you want to compare, use

```
if (myArray[1].equals("milk")) {
    // your code
}
```

---

If you want to compare in for loop, use below

```
String[] myArray = {"bread", "milk", "sugar", "coffee"};
for (int i=0;i<myArray.length;i++) {
    if (myArray[i].equals("milk")) {
        // your code here....
    }
}
```

### [Demo for forloop](http://ideone.com/nz4hOc)

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to print one element, you don't need any loop:

```
System.out.println(myArray[1]); // prints milk, since indices start at 0
```

Read the [Java tutorial about arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) (or any Java introductory book).

Answer (score 0):

You can access any element of array directly using an index. You don't require a loop for it.

For example, if you want to access 2nd element then you have to write:

```
yourArray[1]
// remember for accessing using index
// always use (index - 1) in this case for 2nd element (2-1)
```